# Convert Single SQLSERVER 2005 Script to a SQL SERVER 2000 script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Hi guys first of all I have no expirience with DB programing only basic SQL queries.

I have an sql script that was devolped for SQL Server 2005 FB and I need to run it in SQL server 2000.

**I don't have the original 2005 DB. only a script and a SQL 2000DB**

I found many guides for converting a whole DB but what can I do with  a single script?

it is a very long script that I cannnot share here because of datasecurity issues.

here is the error

[image]
please assist me.

Comment: If you feel you cannot post it here, why not just show us the portions of the code where it fails when you try to run under SQL2000?

Comment: Probably it will directly work without changes. Or it will not. But if you don't try, and don't show it to us, how could we help you???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for specifying index options has changed - look closely at the `WITH` clause:

[SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258260%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] INDEX index_name
    ON { table | view } ( column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] )
[ WITH < index_option > [ ,...n] ]
[ ON filegroup ]
```

[SQL Server 2005 and later](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] INDEX index_name 
    ON <object> ( column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] ) 
    [ INCLUDE ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]
    [ WITH ( <relational_index_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name ( column_name ) 
         | filegroup_name 
         | default 
         }
    ]
[ ; ]
```

The `WITH` clauses in your script use parentheses  and that causes the error. Unless you know that the script sets some specific index options, you can simply remove all the `WITH ( ... )` clauses.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this [10-minute solution](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40531) to learn how to recreate your database using "Generate SQL Server Scripts" wizard. This works while dowangrading from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005, but it may help to downgrade the DB from 2005 to 2000.

there is the link to [MS SQL Server 2005 programmability enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170355%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't have the original 2005 DB. only a script and a SQL 2000DB

Comment: OP is not trying to change a DB version, or move a DB to an older version. He's trying to change a script code of SQL Server 2005 to work in SQL Server 2000. Nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: oh. in this case you need to try to create the database on SQL Server 2000, and the fix the errors (if any) one by one; There is lot of differences between mssql 2K and 2k5, and I'm not sure you can fix all the errors. see the update of my answer to link to the differences.